# Python OpenCV 3: how to use cv2.CV_COMP_HELLINGER

Tags: python, opencv, histogram, image-comparison

I am trying to compare two histograms using compareHist() function, but I can't manage to insert the right comparing method. In the documentation the options are

```
CV_COMP_CORREL Correlation
CV_COMP_CHISQR Chi-Square
CV_COMP_CHISQR_ALT Alternative Chi-Square
CV_COMP_INTERSECT Intersection
CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA Bhattacharyya distance
CV_COMP_HELLINGER Synonym for CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA
CV_COMP_KL_DIV Kullback-Leibler divergence
```

each can be called with cv2.cv.
I am using openCv 3.2.0 and I get the error

```
    d = cv2.compareHist(query_hist, input_hist, cv2.CV_COMP_HELLINGER)
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_COMP_HELLINGER'
```

I have tried both cv2.cv.CV_COMP_HELLINGER and cv2.CV_COMP_HELLINGER but the error is the same

Comment: cv2.COMP_HELLINGER ?

Comment: It gives same error. I've tried it

Comment: it should be cv2.HISTCMP_HELLINGER

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there some documentation where I can find It? I wasn't able to find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cv2.HISTCMP_HELLINGER`.

---

The name has changed in OpenCV 3. You can find the new names [in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga994f53817d621e2e4228fc646342d386):

```
HISTCMP_CORREL
HISTCMP_CHISQR
HISTCMP_INTERSECT
HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA
HISTCMP_HELLINGER       
HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT
HISTCMP_KL_DIV
```